# blockchain mining for non-currency data

Tags: blockchain

A lot of the more widely known uses of blockchain involve the use of cryptocurrencies and it's my (very limited) understanding the mining is used as proof of work to stop too many coins being generated at once and that the larger the pool gets, the longer it takes to mine.

I've also seen lots of articles talk about other uses for blockchain, such as healthcare, mortgages, tracking produce etc. But what I don't understand is how mining is used in these contexts? Surely if it's used for medical records the size of the chain would grow quite quickly, a patient or doctor wouldn't want to have to wait an incredibly long time for their new 'block' to be added to the chain when they visit.

So how does 'mining'/assuring transactions and 'proof of work' work in these other contexts where speed is important?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to understand that mining is not a process of generating new coins (even though it does it is not mining's primary purpose). Primary purpose of mining is to find the next block for the blockchain. Bitcoin provides reward for finding new blocks (Currently 12.5 BTC/Block) and so do other Cryptos.

Because we do need new blocks with 100% randomness we do mine. But with non-currency data we do not need random block we are only concern with data immutability & security.

I hope you get the point if you are still confused feel free to let me know I will try to answer it.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, so in terms of assurance in a non-currency blockchain, you just simply need the network (or a subset of random peers) to verify the integrity of the full chain when a new block is added?